# How to change home page title and description in meta tag

Tags: k2, metadata

I have a test website running joomla 3.4: http://test.amberaviation.com.au
If you look at the source code of the home page. It says

```
<meta name="description" content="change_here" />
<title>change_here</title>
```

[image]

I want to change *description meta* and *title*. I have looked at this [post](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/13485/where-to-edit-meta-description-for-each-article), but it seems it is not matching up in the *global configuration*. (see pic below)

[image]

I suspect it is in K2, but I don't know where to find it.

**Solution**

Module "easy seo joomla" actually change the meta for the home page. The method I found out is to pick a key word in the title or description meta tag. Then do a search in phpmyadmin. Normally, CMS always has this issue, because module overwrite another module, then overwrite another one. The key is to search in db or source file.

Comment: Thanks for showing a solution, but please post it an answer rather than adding it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Module "easy seo joomla" actually change the meta for the home page. The method I found out is to pick a key word in the title or description meta tag. Then do a search in phpmyadmin. Normally, CMS always has this issue, because module overwrite another module, then overwrite another one. The key is to search in db or source file.

Answer (score 2):

The second screenshot you have posted is from the **Global Configuration**. In Global configuration, apart of the Basic Setup/Configuration, you can define settings that would be used globally across your Joomla Installation.

More specifically regarding the **Meta/Robots** settings, what you will set there, usually it will be used when there is no other settings that will override it to produce a different outcome.

Meta Settings of a page can be manipulated/ovewritten in many ways. For example by settings on the **Menu Item** if one is used, through the actual **content item** that the page displays, or the settings of the **component** that gets called, by **3rd party extensions/plugins** -usually SEO ones- and even by the **templates** and **template overrides**.

Now, back to your first screenshot - this doesn't display what you are mentioning in your question. It actually shows a `<title>` and `<meta .. description>`. I also checked your homepage and show the same.

So, consider to update your question with more information about your specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

The page title and meta description are changed through the 'Menus' menu item in the administrative back-end.

1) Choose the page.

2) Go to the 'Page Display' tab.

3) Change the page title via the 'Browser Page Title' input box.

4) Go to the 'Metadata' tab.

5) Change the description via the 'Meta Description' input box.

Answer (score 0):

To change home page title and description in meta tag see the following steps:

1. Put your homepage title into the "Browser Page Title" field.
2. Set "Show Page Heading" to No.
3. If you want to control the rest of the meta description and keywords for the homepage, click "Metadata Options".
4. Save the menu link.

Answer (score 0):

My website uses K2 as the default article manager; and the title on my homepage is a link to the K2 homepage category. I have tried to change the title on the homepage, but it's not possible via K2 config or web template.  However, I found a way...

My solution is:

1. Go to menu manager. My homepage menu points to K2 homepage categories. I change it back to basic Joomla home page article or categories and change page title to show what I want, then Save it.
2. Change homepage menu to point to the K2 homepage article as before. The home page title that you like is still there.  That's it.